# Recursive scp without following links or creating a giant tar file?

Tags: symlink, scp

So I did a recursive scp on my remote fileserver (in another state) and it created an infinite loop of links on my remote web directory...

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/recursive-scp-w-o-following-links-658857/ says that I can can try creating a giant tar file. There is a problem with this though - I'm running the recursive scp on a Linux machine in my office, and I'm copying the files all to my external hard drive, which is in FAT32 format (because I need something that's readable by both UNIX and Windows). FAT32 doesn't support large filesizes. So I would have to try something different.

There's also a rsync option but the Linux machine in my office is very primitive (it's igel) so it doesn't have rsync...

Answer (score 6):

I would not recommend using `scp` for transferring large file trees directly,
because it does not handle neither hard nor soft links properly, also the stream is not compressed.

I'd recommend `cpio` with (de)compression on the fly:

```
ssh user@host "cd /path/to/files && find . | cpio -ov | bzip2 -c" | bunzip2 -c | cpio -ivd
```

Also, `find` can handle additional conditions, like "files must be less than 4G"

```
find . -size -4G | ...
```

To make `cpio` more space-friendly (to handle spaces in file names properly) use

```
find . -print0 | cpio -0 -ivd | ...
```

Comment: `cpio` does not seem to handle large files (>2Gib?), though for purposes of the original question that may be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use `sftp -r` as [`sftp`](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#r) manual says:

> Recursively copy entire directories when uploading and downloading. Note that sftp does not follow symbolic links encountered in the tree traversal.

So

```
sftp -r source@surce_server.com:/source/dir .
```

does exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create the tar file before sending it. You can make it on the fly:

```
cd /source/dir
tar -cf - . | ssh 'cd /destination/directory && tar -xf -'
```

This does require that the remote server accept ssh shell connections, not just scp connections. In theory, it is possible to send arbitrary file trees to the remote side that don't correspond to anything like the local file structure, but I don't know of any existing tool to do this.

If symbolic links are a problem, you can make a copy of a directory tree that doesn't include symbolic links and that uses up negligible space, assuming the source tree is on a filesystem that supports hard links (so any native unix filesystem, or NTFS, but not FAT). I'm assuming GNU utilities here:

```
cd /source/dir
mkdir ../regular-files-only
cp -al . ../regular-files-only
find ../regular-file-only \! -type f \! -type d -delete
```

You could also use sftp. `sftp -r` does not follow symbolic links, unlike `scp -r`.